# CollectionView margin not the same

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

i'm trying to create a simple collectionView like pinterest. I've reached a problem i've set the margins like in the image, but as u can see the middle margin is 20 since both right and left is 10 how can i make so that its also 10. i've tried changing some values, but it is not working.

[image]

## for fitting all orientations

Is there a better way?

```
func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    
    return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView!.frame.width/2-20, self.collectionView!.frame.width/2-20+50)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use auto layout and view constraints. This will allow you to have each tile maintain its spacing and scale for different orientations.

[see the apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: But i cant use contraints on a UICollectionViewCells. is there a better way to make it fit all orientations than what i've done in sizeForItemAtIndexPath?